# How to convert levelDB read stream into sync method

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronization, leveldb

```
let temp = [];

db.createReadStream({ keys: true, values: false })
  .on('data', data => {

   temp.push(data);

  })
console.log(temp);
```

I am trying to iterate out each key from a LevelDB database and send the data back to the client, but the createReadStream method is asynchronous
so the client response code is firing before it has finished iterating through the database, I was wondering if there was any way to make it into a synchronous function and fire the response only after everything has finished..

Comment: I need the same ... no info about it :(

Comment: @ch3ll0v3k https://javascript.info/async-await read up about async await, it should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The code is waiting for the stream to be completed before sending it back to the client.

```js
import level from 'level'

const db = level('db', { valueEncoding: 'json' })

export async function CreateReadStream (option = {}) {
  let array = []
  try {    
    const readStream = db.createReadStream(option)
    for await (const data of readStream) {
      array.push(data)
    }

    return array
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}
```